# Seaborn's Violin plot can't be chained in for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, plot, seaborn

I have the following dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test_data = pd.read_csv('./data.csv',index_col = 0,header = 0)
```

[image]

and I wanted to explore my data. I can plot multiple scatter plots in succession using a for loop:

```
for c_type in sorted(list(set(test_data['Designation'].values))):
    fil_test_data = test_data[test_data['Designation'] == c_type]
    t_plt = sns.lmplot(x = 'Age',
                      y = 'Property_1',
                      hue = 'Timepoint',
                      data = fil_test_data)
```

[image]

However, it seems that I can't accomplish this if I switch to Seaborn's Violinplot (or a categorical-type plot like boxplot):

```
for cat_column in test_data.columns[:4]:
    test_data[cat_column] = test_data[cat_column].astype('category')
for greek in sorted(list(set(test_data['Designation'].values))):
    fil_test_data = test_data[test_data['Designation'] == greek]
    t_plt = sns.violinplot(x = 'Group',
                      y = 'Property_1',
                      hue = 'Timepoint',
                      data = test_data)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.set_title('Designation {}'.format(greek))
```

[image]

Is there a reason why plotting violinplots (or a categorical plot) can't work in a for loop?

Comment: `lmplot` is a figure level function. It produces its own figure. `violinplot` is a axes level function, it plots to the current axes. You can produce a new figure via `plt.figure()`.

Comment: That makes more sense: If I try to save a violin plot, I have to use plt.savefig() and can't use plot_name.savefig(). Thanks for the advice!